# Zend Framework: Cannot echo doctype or stylesheet path; echoing Object id # instead

Tags: zend-framework

I've FTP'd my Quickstart project from a Windows machine to a Linux box and I'm getting unexpected results from these statements:

```
echo $this->doctype();
echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css');
```

My output should look like this (Windows machine):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="/css/main.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <title>Sample Zend app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is my layout</h1>
    <p>This is index.phtml</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my output on from Linux box:

```
Object id #37
<html lang="en">
<head>
    Object id #49
    <title>Sample Zend app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is my layout</h1>
    <p>This is index.phtml</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why my statements echoing the doctype and path to my stylesheet are producing *Object id #xx*?

Thanks in advance.

Also- I've provided my Boostrap, application.ini, and layout:

**Bootstrap.php:**

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

    protected function _initDocType() {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');
        $view->doctype('HTML5');
    }
}
```

**application.ini:**

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.view[] = 
[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

**layout.phtml:**

```
<?php echo $this->doctype(); ?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css'); ?>
    <title>Sample Zend app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is my layout/h1>
    <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Windows: 5.3.8 | Linux: 5.1.6

Comment: I guess you found the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

The php documentation says that __toString() worked differently pre 5.2 . I'd upgrade your php or call the function directly eg

```
$something->__toString();
```

see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring